# Unable run the code in wordpress custom widget area

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have created a widget area in WordPress 4.8 version, in that widget area I am taking text widget.

Code:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-x'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-x'); });
</script>
</div>
```

widget creation code:

```
global $blog_id;
if( $blog_id == '2' ) {

    function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Header Widget Area for RBI',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );

}
<?php
global $blog_id;
if( $blog_id == '2' ) {

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="header-widget-area" class="chw-widget-area widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-header-widget' ); ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; } ?>
```

the above script if we place directly in header.php or footer.php file it is working fine, but in text widget not working any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the shortcode to accomplish this.

First, you enable the shortcode in widgets with the following line in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Next, you create a shortcode:

```
function mygooglead_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
<div id='div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-x'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-x'); });
</script>
</div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();  
}
add_shortcode( 'mygooglead', 'mygooglead_shortcode' );
```

Finally. you use the shortcode in widget by putting this in it:

```
[mygooglead]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot normally put PHP directly in a widget, Wordpress doesn't allow it. There are a few plugins that let you do that but I can't vouch for any one in particular so I'll let you find it on your own.

Comment: the above is not php script it is js script which related to google ads